# Laravel accessing array of sql data for displaying

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, sqlite

I have an array being returned by a DB::Select statement which I would like to pass into a for statement in my page to display, but when doing so am met with the following error:
[image]

My array looks like such:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [company_name] => Apple [count(*)] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [company_name] => Facebook[count(*)] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [company_name] => Netflix [count(*)] => 1 ) )
```

PHP as so:

```php
<div class=" mt-5 text-center">
        @if ($metric_data)
            @foreach ($metric_data as $metric_datas)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $metric_data->company_name }}</td>
                    <td>s</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p>No items found.</p>
        @endif
    </div>
```

I am not sure why It cannot access it?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: First of all, try not to post code/errors as an image; makes it a bit harder for us to help . Second, you're doing a loop, `@foreach ($metric_data as $metric_datas)`, but you then call `{{ $metric_data->company_name }}`. That should be `{{ $metric_datas->company_name }}`; watch your variable names.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to return the [count(*)] in the second <td>? Laravel doesn't like the '*' @TimLewis

Comment: `$metric_datas->{"count(*)"}` _should_ work, but it might be better to change to just `count` or similar 

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code with this foreach variables placed wrong that's all

```
<div class=" mt-5 text-center">
    @if ($metric_data)
        @foreach ($metric_datas as $metric_data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $metric_data->company_name }}</td>
                <td>s</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No items found.</p>
    @endif
</div>
```